# How to search for a specific value (email and password) for login purposes between two tables (tbl_admin & tbl_users) in database codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
<?php

class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function login($email, $pass)
    {
        // $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_admin', 'patient_record',['email' => $email, 'password' => $pass]);
        // return $query->row();

        $query = $this->db->select('ta.*', 'pr.*')
            ->from('tbl_admin ta')
            ->join('patient_record pr', 'ta.admin_id = pr.patient_id')
            ->where('ta.email', $email)
            ->where('ta.password', $pass)
            ->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
}

?>
```

I need to search for tables admin table (tbL_admin) and patient table (patient_rec) with the matching email & password value

this current code of mine only seems to get results from tbl_admin table

Answer (score 0):

You can make two queries with UNION.

You are using Codeigniter 3 and the query builder has no function to do this, it only exists since version 4.

In CI3 try this way

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        $this->load->database();
    }
        
    public function login($email, $pass)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT ta.* FROM tbl_admin ta WHERE ta.email = ? AND ta.password = ?
                UNION
                SELECT pr.* FROM tbl_admin ta WHERE pr.email = ? AND pr.password = ?";
    
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, [$email, $user, $email, $user]);
    
        return $query->getRow();
    }
}
```

I have not sanitized the values ​​received by the method because I do not know where they come from, you have to take care of this

Or, if you want to opt for version 4 instead

[Codeigniter 4 Union Query Builder](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?#union-queries)